# AWS S3 JS SDK - Upload timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm getting the below error while uploading video files (35MB and 633MB). I get this error after about 2-3 mins. while the file is being uploaded.

```
"TimeoutError: Timeout
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/js/libraries/aws-sdk.min.js:34:25067)"
```

[image]

Below is the code I'm using

```
AWSHelper.storage.s3.putObject({
    Key: payload.fileName,
    Body: blob,
    ACL: 'private',
    Metadata: metadata
}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(err.stack)
});
```

We have set the timeout of 25 seconds but the error received is after 2-3 mins

Comment: Would recommend that you take out the bucket and region name from the screen shot.

Comment: @Yogesh_D: Removed. Thanks..

Comment: I'm having the same issue - Were you able to find a solution?